# Yahoo Pipes Only One Item per Hour

Tags: yahoo-pipes

Hello I'm building a Yahoo Pipe to feed my Facebook Fanpage. I have plenty of RSS Feeds which stream pictures and I want to limit the output to one picture per hour. But I'm completely new to pipes and can't find an understandable tutorial. Pipe looks like that

```
RSS1   RSS2 ... RSSn
  |      |       |
  +-----UNION----+
         |
     PIPE OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using this algorithm:

1. Create a new field that contains the date truncated to hours
2. Use the **Unique** operator on this new field to get only one item per hour

You could implement this using pipes like this:

1. Copy `pubDate` to, say, `datepart`, using a **Rename** operator, with params:

   - `item.pubDate`
   - **Copy As**
   - `datepart`
2. Truncate `datepart`, using a **Regex** operator, with params:

   - **In** = `item.datepart`
   - **replace** = `^(.{13}).*`
   - **with** = `$1`

   That is, since date fields are represented as `YYYY-mm-DDTHH:MM:ssZ` we take the first 13 characters to get the date part up until the hour and discard the rest. For example if `pubDate` was `2013-11-03T13:34:37` then we get `2013-11-03T13`.
3. Use a **Unique** operator based on `item.datepart` to filter items

As a simple demo, I put together a pipe for you that shows 1 question per month tagged `yahoo-pipes` on stackoverflow:

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=72fea3931e145324f308f0d5f6852d93

Note that you will get different results depending on where you put these elements. For example, you could put this logic *after* your union, to get one image per hour from all your source feeds combined. Or you could put this logic *before* your union, to get one image per hour per feed.

You might also ask, in case of multiple images per hour, which one will be picked? The first one. I think the default ordering is by *pubDate*. To make Yahoo Pipes pick a different item, insert an appropriate **Sort** operator before **Unique**.